# TSQL show only first row

Tags: t-sql, select, limit

I have the following TSQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MyTable1.Date
  FROM MyTable1 
INNER JOIN MyTable2 
ON MyTable1.Id = MyTable2.Id
WHERE Name = 'John' ORDER BY MyTable1.Date DESC
```

It retrieves a long list of Dates, but I only need the first one, the one in the first row.

How can I get it?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use [`TOP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx?ppud=4):

```
SELECT TOP 1 MyTable1.Date
FROM MyTable1 
INNER JOIN MyTable2 
  ON MyTable1.Id = MyTable2.Id
WHERE Name = 'John' 
ORDER BY MyTable1.Date DESC
```

If you need to use `DISTINCT`, then you can use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 x.Date
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT MyTable1.Date
   FROM MyTable1 
   INNER JOIN MyTable2 
     ON MyTable1.Id = MyTable2.Id
    WHERE Name = 'John' 
) x
ORDER BY x.Date DESC
```

Or even:

```
SELECT MAX(MyTable1.Date)
FROM MyTable1 
INNER JOIN MyTable2 
  ON MyTable1.Id = MyTable2.Id
WHERE Name = 'John' 
--ORDER BY MyTable1.Date DESC
```

Comment: @user523129 depending on what you need, you might be able to use `MAX()` since you are only returning one date value.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options here. You can use TOP(1) as Taryn mentioned. But according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the purposes of limiting the rows returned it is better to use OFFSET and FETCH.

> We recommend that you use the OFFSET and FETCH clauses instead of the TOP clause to implement a query paging solution and limit the number of rows sent to a client application.
>
> Using OFFSET and FETCH as a paging solution requires running the query one time for each "page" of data returned to the client application. For example, to return the results of a query in 10-row increments, you must execute the query one time to return rows 1 to 10 and then run the query again to return rows 11 to 20 and so on.

Assuming, the solution for your problem using OFFSET and FETCH approach could be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MyTable1.Date
  FROM MyTable1 
INNER JOIN MyTable2 
ON MyTable1.Id = MyTable2.Id
WHERE Name = 'John' ORDER BY MyTable1.Date DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
```