# SQL - Find max value and then corresponding column

Tags: sql, max, multiple-columns

SQL query: 3 column table, searching "John" 's max value returning City only. 
Data:

```
Name | City | Value <br>
John | LDN | 50 <br>
Joey | MCR | 12<br>
Dave | BHM | 5<br>
John | NTH | 56 <br>
```

Desired result: NTH (4th row)
How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What would be the expected result if John, LDN also had 56?

Comment: T-SQL. If John, LDN has 56? Luckily I'm not too worried about this but it does raise a good point as to what would take priority!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL show only first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688576/tsql-show-only-first-row). Just order by Value instead of Date. In [how does SELECT TOP works when no order by is specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245322/how-does-select-top-works-when-no-order-by-is-specified) the answer is in the Question and in [Select Top N Records Ordered by X, But Have Results in Reverse Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572496/select-top-n-records-ordered-by-x-but-have-results-in-reverse-order) the answer is in the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select city from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by name order by value desc) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1 and name='John'
```

Alternatively,

```
select city from tablename t 
where name='John' and value = (select max(value) from tablename t1 where t.name=t1.name)
```

Comment: Thanks Fahmi, feels like a good introduction for myself to the Row_number function!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and some way of limiting the results:

```
select t.*
from t
order by value desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Some databases use `select top (1)` or `limit 1` to limit to a single row.